# React Native - componentDidUpdate causing app to run slow

Tags: react-native

I ran into this problem messing around with other components should as `componentDidMount` or `ComponentWillMount`. In order for `this.state` to update itself when it navigates into another screen, it needs `componentDidUpdate` for data fetching.

```js
constructor(props)
{

  super(props);

  this.state = {
  isLoading: true,
  username: '',
  dataSource: ''
};
AsyncStorage.getItem("username").then((value) => {
  this.setState({"username": value})
});
}
saveData(value){
    AsyncStorage.setItem("username", value);
    this.setState({"username": value});
}
componentDidUpdate() {


      return fetch(`http://www.example.com/React/user-profile.php?username=${this.state.username}` , {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       }

      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson,
            },function() {
              // In this block you can do something with new state.
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

When I use other components other than `componentDidUpdate` the screen does not display anything and the state does not change. Is there a component that can update like `componentDidUpdate` and not cause performance issues? Also to note, when I used `componentDidMount` the performance didn't drop, but the state did not change.

```js
 render() {


    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }


      return(

         <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
         <ScrollView>

         <FlatList

           data={ this.state.images}

           ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


           renderItem={({item}) => <View>


           <RkCard style={{width:'75%', marginLeft: 50, marginBottom: 50, backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5'}}>
            <Lightbox>
             <FastImage rkCardImg source={{uri:`http://www.example.com/profiles/uploads/${item.images}`,
             headers:{ Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
             priority: FastImage.priority.high,
              }}
               resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
               style={{width: '100%'}}/>
               </Lightbox>

             <View rkCardContent>
             <Makiko
                  label={'Comment'}
                  iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
                  iconName={'comment'}
                  iconColor={'white'}
                  inputStyle={{ color: '#db786d' }}
                />
             </View>
             <View rkCardFooter>

               <Text> {item.note}</Text>
             </View>
           </RkCard>


           </View>


         }

         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
         removeClippedSubviews

      />


         </ScrollView>
         </View>
       );
     }
   }
```

Comment: If you use componentDidMount for fetching data and storing them in state, the state is changing for sure. ComponentDidMount is use for fetching data and store them into state or redux. Are you sure you have your data in response.json() ? You should also have a look here http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Comment: @GabrielDiez Yeah, I am using the data. Do I need to put any parameters in the `componentDidMount`?

Comment: No you don’t need to put any parameters in componentDidMount. Can you post your render method please ?

Comment: @GabrielDiez I added the render above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using componentDidUpdate() to do a network request and update the state, which is fine, but this re-triggers componentDidUpdate(). So it is being called over and over again. This is also addressed in the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

So you should use the arguments to check if you need the network request. For instance: you could do something like this:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

    // check if dataSource state is still empty
    if (!prevState.dataSource) {

         // Your networking code
         return fetch(...)
             .then(...)
             .catch(...)
    }
}
```

Now the networking call is only executed when it needs to be, and componentDidUpdate() isn't called over and over again.

Note: if the dataSource state isn't necessary empty, then you can also compare the current state / props to the previous state / props in the if(...) statement.

Comment: Thank you, but when I do insert this, I get an undefined variable `dataSource` @dentemm

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the performance and I can see the data! I would of never thought of doing this. I will read into the official document too.

Comment: Glad it works! Best of luck with the rest of your application!

Answer (score 2):

You should never call `this.setState();` inside `componentWillUpdate`,
Because once it updates the state, it will again call componentWillUpdate and so on... so it would be a never ending process, You can always use `if else` blocks to check whether to update or not, by checking the previous props as it gets called with componentWillUpdate gets called with ( prevProps, prevState )

Comment: great answer. Indeed that was my problem